# Make a subscription start on the first of the month in php

Tags: php

I have this code that starts a subscription the day after purchase:

`$subscription['START'] = date( 'mdY', mktime( 0, 0, 0, date( 'm' ), date( 'd' ) + 1, date( 'y' ) ) );`

I would like to make it start on the first day of the month - it's hard for me to test on the current site - as it is live and I don't want to mess things up while testing. I'm curious if this is the correct way to do it:

`$subscription['START'] = date( 'mdY', mktime( 0, 0, 0, date( 'm' ), '01', date( 'y' ) ) );`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your method is right but you can also use smaller version

```
$subscription['START'] = date('m01Y');
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another question about the code above, am I reading it correctly that it first gets the current date 'mdy' then using mktime figures out the next day? If that is so, wouldn't I need it find the current day so that it can know where it is reference to the next first of the month, or am I over thinking this...